# Call a query for each row returned by a query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a problem, with every employee in the 'employee' table I need to call a SELECT query in the 'KPI' table. I use Cursor to read each value in the table 'employee':

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp6 ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE temp varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

    DEClARE cs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT `full_name` FROM `employee`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    OPEN cs1;
    fLoop: LOOP
        FETCH cs1 INTO temp;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE fLoop;
      END IF;

      [FROM KPI TABLE, QUERY TO GET KPI OF EMPLOYEE WITH NAME 'temp']

 END LOOP fLoop;
 CLOSE cs1;

END$$
DELIMITER;
```

But I got the error message: [Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l357X.png)

Someone please help me where I was wrong? Thanks you.

Comment: Why do you need to do this using a cursor, it could just be a single select query. SELECT * FROM `KPI` AS k INNER JOIN `employee` AS e ON k.`full_name` = e.`full_name`

Comment: Thanks you, I need to calculate the KPI of each employee, my idea is to use cursor to identify each Employee and pass this value to the SELECT query to calculate. How can i do that with innerjoin?

Comment: If you have many KPI's per employee which one(s) do you want and how do you identify them (by date,complete,in progress, for this year?)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cursor here. Just a join `KPI` and `employee` on `full_name`.

```
SELECT k.*
       FROM `KPI` k
            INNER JOIN `employee` e
                       ON e.`full_name` = k.`full_name`;
```

Comment: Thanks you, with Innerjoin you will have many records for the same employee, how can I calculate the KPI for each employee? My idea is to use cursor to identify each Employee and pass this value to the SELECT query to calculate.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, if there are more records for an employee in `KPI` you'll get more that one record. But so you do in your cursor approach.